# proguard release error

Tags: java, android, mvp, proguard

Включил в проекте proguard, apk собирается, все хорошо, но приложение не работает)

Proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontoptimize

# Keep Butterknife
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
@butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
@butterknife.* <methods>;
}

# Keep Jackson stuff
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.** { *; }

# Keep Retrofit
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@retrofit.** *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
@retrofit.** *;
}

# Keep Picasso
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** { *; }
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
@com.squareup.picasso.** *;
}

#Keep Usafe
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe

#Keep Moxy
-keep class **$$PresentersBinder
-keep class **$$State
-keep class **$$ParamsHolder
-keep class **$$ViewStateClassNameProvider
-keepnames class * extends com.arellomobile.mvp.*

#Keep Anotations
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.** { *; }
```

Ошибка происходит в презентере

```
@InjectViewState
public class MainPresenter extends MvpPresenter<MainView> {

@Inject
Service service;

public MainPresenter() {
    CamApp.getAppComponent().inject(this);
}

public void goLoginActivity(){
    getViewState().goLoginActivity();
}

public void goListCamerasActivity(){
    isAvailableServer();
}

private void isAvailableServer(){
    Observable<Response> observable = RxUtils.wrapRetrofitCallIsAvailableServer(service.isAvailableServer(""));
    RxUtils.wrapAsync(observable)
            .subscribe(server -> {
                List<String> cookie = server.headers().values("Set-Cookie");
                AuthUtils.setSessionId(cookie.get(0).split(";")[0].split("=")[1]);
                AuthUtils.setToken(cookie.get(1).split(";")[0].split("=")[1]);
                requestLoginDemo();
            }, exception -> getViewState().showError(R.string.unknown_error));
}
```

Пишет что поле service - No such instance field: 'service'. При выключенном proguard все работает нормально.

service

```
public class Service {
private CamAPI mCamApi;

public Service(CamAPI mCamApi) {
    this.mSpaceCamApi = mSpaceCamApi;
}

public Call<BackendData> passwordRecovery(String cookie, String token, String email){
    return mCamApi.passwordRecovery(cookie, token, email);
}

public Call<Response<ResponseBody>> getArchiveLink(String devCode, String date){
    return mCamApi.getArchiveLink(devCode, date);
}

public Call<BackendData> isAvailableServer(String cookie){
    return TextUtils.isEmpty(cookie) ? mCamApi.isAvailableServer() : mCamApi.isAvailableServer(cookie);
}

public Call<BackendData> login(String cookie, String token, String username, String password, boolean remember){
    return mCamApi.login(cookie, token, username, password, remember);
}

public Call<BackendData> getAllCameraList(String cookie, String token){
    return mSpaceCamApi.getAllCameraList(cookie, token);
}

public Call<BackendData> getCamera(String cookie, String token, Long id, boolean isMobile){
    return mCamApi.getCamera(cookie, token, id, isMobile);
}

public Call<BackendData> ptz(String cookie, String token, Long id, String com){
    return mCamApi.ptz(cookie, token, id, com);
}

public Call<BackendData> logout(String cookie, String token){
    return mCamApi.logout(cookie, token);
}
```

}

Comment: Похоже, что это даггер не заинжектил, а не мокси. Советую попробовать для теста убрать @inject  и ручками установить туда значение в конструкторе

Comment: Уточните, Inject от dagger'а или каких-либо других библиотек?.. Для даггера тоже есть правила для proguard.

Comment: Да, попробуйте превратить @Inject Service service в обычное поле Service, а в конструкторе вызовите service = new Service. Исключительно для проверки. Так мы сможем понять несколько больше =)

Comment: для даггера 2 вроде не нужно никаких правил в proguard

Comment: Добавил сервис класс в первое сообщение. В сервисе добавил конструктор без параметров, в презентере попробовал создать объект через new в конструкторе, пишет тоже самое - No such instance field: 'service. Если включаю  в proguard -dontobfuscate - все работает.

Comment: Очень странная проблема, потому что Moxy в данном случае никак не меняет MainPresenter. Она только добавляет классы. Но они тоже никак не влияют на вызов конструктора презентера. Могу предложить только убрать из gradle dependencies moxy-compiler. Тогда ни один Moxy-класс не будет сгенерирован и значит Moxy никак не будет реагировать на Proguard.